Write protect columns but allow Auto-Filter in Excel created with ClosedXML
I am using ClosedXML with C# to create a Excel Worksheet.
The requirement is to

Allow Auto-Filer on all columns
Allow edit only form column "B", write protect the remaining columns
Allow column formatting and addition of columns.

The following code though write-protects all the columns, and disables the use of the Auto-Filter (even though the dropdown icon is visible).
var exWB = new XLWorkbook();
var exWS = exWB.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
exWS.Cell("A1").Value = "ID";
exWS.Cell("B1").Value = "Name";

exWS.Cell("A2").Value = "25";
exWS.Cell("B2").Value = "Fred";

exWS.Cell("A3").Value = "28";
exWS.Cell("B3").Value = "Burt";

.
.

exWS.Columns().AdjustToContents();
exWS.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter();
exWS.Protect();
exWS.Column("B").Style.Protection.SetLocked(false);


exWB.SaveAs("my.xlsx");

This gives a spreadsheet where column A is locked but B is not as per requirement, but the auto-filter does not open the options (stuck on ALL).

The answer was to use the AutoFilter option on the Protect command (I also need to allow FormatCells and InsertColumns for another requirement).
exWS.Columns().AdjustToContents();
exWS.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter();
exWS.Protect().AllowElement(XLSheetProtectionElements.FormatCells)
              .AllowElement(XLSheetProtectionElements.InsertColumns)
              .AllowElement(XLSheetProtectionElements.AutoFilter);
exWS.Column("B").Style.Protection.SetLocked(false);

